# Interpolate SASS in HAML for background-image: -> Object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, sass

I'm trying to have a background-image per list item to be dependent on which object it's linking to! Shouldn't be too hard, but I couldn't figure out how to do it in SASS. Here's my attempt from HAML, because that's where I'll be iterating through a collection of different facilities:

#### app/views/facilities/index.html.haml

```
#facility
  - @facilities.each do |facility|
    %ul#facilities
      %li
        :sass
          background-image: url(#{image_tag "logos/#{facility.image}.jpg"})
        = link_to facility.name, facility_path(facility)
```

But the error I'm getting looks like the following:

#### error

`Invalid CSS after "url(": expected ")", was "<img alt="Thebi..." Arounnd line 6`
For one of the generated images.

It can't be this difficult...can it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use sass for this, you'll pay a significant performance penalty for no benefit. Just use inline html styles:

```
#facility
  - @facilities.each do |facility|
    %ul#facilities
      %li{:style => "background-image: url(#{image_path "logos/#{facility.image}.jpg"})"}
        = link_to facility.name, facility_path(facility)
```

Comment: +1, I only solved the image_path error and did not correct the actual output.

Comment: In rails 5 + HAML 5 I get this error  uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove your image tag.

Currently your css expands to:

```
background-image: url('<img src=""</img>')
```

You should change it to:

```
background-image: url("public/images/#{facility.image}.jpg")
```

I'll have a check see if there is a helper for it.

EDIT: the helper is [image_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path) so you need:

```
background-image: url(#{image_path "logos/#{facility.image}.jpg"})
```

Comment: Weird, now I get the following error:  
`Properties aren't allowed at the root of a document.`  
Any idea?

Comment: You get that error because sass is generating a stylesheet, not inline style properties for the containing element. you have to nest the :sass filter inside a `<style>` element and it needs a selector to be valid css.

Comment: What might that look like? how to wrap `<style>` around the `:sass` filter and only applied to the `<li>` tag.